# Error - Receiver has no segue with identifier 'detailLoad'

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, segue

I know this question has been asked before but I have not found a solution to the problem. 
I have two ViewControllers in IB and they are connected with a segue I want to fire manually. The segue is connected from the ViewController to the destination ok and the identifier is identical to the one in the code, I have copied and pasted, yet when I try to segue it crashes with 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'detailLoad''.

```
- (void)stuff
{
    NSLog(@"Tap");

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailLoad" sender:self];

}
```

Above is the code I use for the segue, yes I know it's called "stuff" but this is a test project not an actual project.

As i say the segue is named correctly and is all connected properly but it still gives this error as in it cannot find the segue. The project is set up for iOS 6. I have set up NSLogs in `prepareForSegue` but this is not fired as the error seems to be in the `performSegueWithIdentier` line.
Any ideas as to why?
Thanks

Comment: You don't say what kind of object `self` is in that code.  If it's a subclass of `UIViewController` make sure that the source of the segue is set to the correct controller class and that the start really is the controller instead of some view.

Comment: Yes, its a subclass of `UIViewController` and yes the segue is linked up to the correct ViewController and not its `UIView`

Comment: Hmm - what is being tapped? Maybe you linked it to a button... What does the text in the list view (left side) of the storyboard say? Does it say "segue from view controller to..." etc. explicitly?

Comment: This either means that you have misspelled the identifier or you are potentially not actually using a storyboard, what is the result of `NSLog(@"%@", self.storyboard);` from inside the viewController?

Comment: It does say segue from view controller and no I haven't misspelled it. The result of `NSLog(@"%@", self.storyboard);` is `<UIStoryboard: 0x885b830>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under iOS 6. I had been invoking the deprecated call presentModalViewController prior to the segue "being lost". Replacing that with the now preferred presentViewControllerAnimated the issue went away.